# Switch between versions of blender

Tags: versions

Say you have Blender 2.8 and want to use 2.79 for any reason. For me, it's because I prefer internal render because it's easy to use. What's the best way to switch between different versions of Blender.

What I tried doing was to go to Blender's file location and open one of the version folders, but that didn't work as they didn't contain any separate shortcuts.

[image].

Comment: There should be a blender.exe for each version. You can always download the .ZIP versions from blender.org and extract them into your preferred folders and run them from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are working with Windows...
With the Windows Explorer visit the directory of Blender 2.8.
Find the Blender.exe (or how it is called under Windows...I am Linux guy...;)
Select that file
Click with the right mouse button it and select "Create shortcut here".
Move the newly created shortcut onto your desktop.
Do the same for the other version of blender.
If you will get an filename conflict, rename Blender.exe to Blender279.exe / Blender280.exe beforhand.

Answer (score 0):

When I installed 2.80 (I previously had 2.79), it created the 2.80 folder, but the main Blender exe was in the parent folder, so it overwrote the 2.79 exe which was previously there, so I could no longer use 2.79.

I found this very annoying as I wanted to be able to revert to 2.79 if I wanted to do something quickly because I haven't got used to the new 2.80 UI yet.

It seems to me that if you want two versions at the same time, you have to specify a completely different location when you install the second one.